# How to use generateMetaData with Suspense in Next13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I tried to add a loading UI to my next 13 server-side pages to improve some user experience.

I'm using `Suspense` to display my custom `skeleton loader` component. Then I got a problem with `generateMetaData`, my `metadata` uses data from `backend` so it will need to fetch the data first

My custom `loader` not showing when I have `generateMetadata` on my `page.jsx`.

Is there any way to implement `Suspense` on `generateMetadata` ? or a better way to implement `loader` in Next 13?

Note: I'm not using the global `loading.jsx` file because some of my pages have different loading skeleton

```
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import { getDictionary } from '@/lib/dictionary'
import AnimeDetailContent from './content'
import AnimeDetailLoader from './loader'
import { fetchDetail } from '@/services/anime-api'


export async function generateMetadata({ params: { animeId } }) {
  const animeDetail = await fetchDetail({ animeId })

  return {
    title: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_NAME} || ${animeDetail.title}`
  }
}

async function AnimeDetailPage({ params: { lang, animeId } }) {
  const dictionary            = await getDictionary(lang)
  const detailPageTranslation = dictionary.page.detail

  return (
    <div className="px-1 pt-20 container lg:mx-auto min-h-screen">
      <Suspense fallback={ <AnimeDetailLoader /> }>
        <AnimeDetailContent
          animeId={ animeId }
          translation={ detailPageTranslation }
        />
      </Suspense>
    </div>

  )
}

export default AnimeDetailPage
```

Comment: loading.tsx is not only global file, you can add it directly to your page folder, making it specific to this page

Comment: Ok thats work too, thanks for let me know. But seems its not solving my issue, the loader still not showing when i have async  process on my `generateMetadata`